# What happens exactly when I call an async method?

Tags: dart

What if I have

```
_asyncMethod();

print("Hi");
```

The method is executed before print but the method stops at its first await and then print is reached?

OR

The method is NOT executed, the print is reached and then the method is executed, like it was called with a Future.delayed with Duration(seconds:0) call?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`_asyncMethod()` is executed.  As much of it as possible is executed synchronously.  That is, `_asyncMethod` is executed until it reaches its first `await` (or `return` statement), which is syntactic sugar for returning a `Future` to the caller.  Since the caller does not itself `await` the returned `Future`, the caller resumes executing, which in this case will call `print("Hi")`.